# intellij idea: no scala sdk in module

Tags: intellij-idea, scala, sbt

Идея не видит scala. Плагин установлен, при создании проекта отсутствует опция создать scala object.

[image: no scala object]

Когда я тупо создаю пустой файл с расширением scala, я получаю уведомление:

[image: no scala sdk in module]

Плагин точно установлен:

[image: Scala plugin]

Scala также установлена:

[image: scala]

Не понимаю как решить данную проблему. Советы которые могу погуглить, либо не работают, либо не понятны в силу отсутствия опыта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плагин Scala установлен в IDEA. Это даёт возможность подключать Scala к вашим проектам.
Но к текущему проекту язык не подключён. Сделать это можно несколькими способами.

Способ первый. Самый простой.
Нажать на "Setup Scala SDK" внутри файла с Scala кодом. У вас есть такой выбор на второй картинке.
После этого вам нужно выбрать какую версию Scala вы хотите использовать в этом проекте. Если вы до этого её не использовали, то вам нужно одну из версий скачать нажав на кнопку "Create..." на второй-же картинке.

Способ второй. В IDEA в левой панели проекта выбрать папку с проектом (папка с синим квадратом) - и вызвать контекстное меню правой кнопкой мыши. Выбрать "Add Framework Support". Выбрать Scala, и дальше всё будет похоже на путь из первого способа.